# Яндекс карты. Поиск только внутри города

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Ребята помогите плз. Есть форма оформления заказа. Меня попросили доработать код. Суть проблемы : Есть что то типа селекта где можно выбрать город. И инпут в который вводится Улица дом и квартира. Но когда вводишь адрес то он выдает еще другие города, а нужно что бы подсказки были только выбранного города. [Скрин](http://prntscr.com/nac0jy) .

```js
function initThree() {
    // Подключаем поисковые подсказки к полю ввода.
    var suggestView = new ymaps.SuggestView('suggest'),
        map, placemark;
    var stateObj = {
        center: [52.275555, 104.281047],
        zoom: 12,
        controls: []
    };
    createMap(stateObj, 'Россия, Иркутск');
    // При клике по кнопке запускаем верификацию введёных данных.
    $('#suggest').on('blur', function () {
        geocode();
    });
    $('#suggest').on('keyup', function () {
        geocode();
    });

    function geocode() {
        // Забираем запрос из поля ввода.
        var request = $('#suggest').val();  // это инпут
        var myCity = $('#ya-dostavka').text();  // это значение селекта
        // Геокодируем введённые данные.
        ymaps.geocode('Россия, ' + myCity + ', ' + request).then(function (res) {
            var obj = res.geoObjects.get(0);
            showResult(obj);
        }, function (e) {
            console.log(e)
        })
    }
    function showResult(obj) {
        // Удаляем сообщение об ошибке, если найденный адрес совпадает с поисковым запросом.
        $('#suggest').removeClass('input_error');
        $('#notice').css('display', 'none');

        var mapContainer = $('#maps-chekout'),
            bounds = obj.properties.get('boundedBy'),
            // Рассчитываем видимую область для текущего положения пользователя.
            mapState = ymaps.util.bounds.getCenterAndZoom(
                bounds,
                [mapContainer.width(), mapContainer.height()]
            ),
            // Сохраняем укороченный адрес для подписи метки.
            shortAddress = [obj.getThoroughfare(), obj.getPremiseNumber(), obj.getPremise()].join(' ');
        // Убираем контролы с карты.
        mapState.controls = [];
        // Создаём карту.
        createMap(mapState, shortAddress);
    }

    function createMap(state) {
        // Если карта еще не была создана, то создадим ее и добавим метку с адресом.
        if (!map) {
            map = new ymaps.Map('maps-chekout', state);
            placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
                map.getCenter(), {
                    iconCaption: false,
                    balloonContent: false
                }, {
                    preset: 'islands#redDotIconWithCaption'
                });
            map.geoObjects.add(placemark);
            // Если карта есть, то выставляем новый центр карты и меняем данные и позицию метки в соответствии с найденным адресом.
        } else {
            map.setCenter(state.center, state.zoom);
            placemark.geometry.setCoordinates(state.center);
            placemark.properties.set({iconCaption: false, balloonContent: false});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Геокодер вернет результат даже в том случае, если запрошенного адреса не существует - будет выбран максимально подходящий.

Если выбор Геокодера принципиален - можно указать в параметрах запроса results=1 и ограничивать область поиска. Но это все не панацея.

Для подсказок нужно использовать соответствующий функционал:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/suggest-docpage

И тогда выдача будет жестко ограничена:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var city = 'город Иркутск';
  var address = new ymaps.SuggestView(
    'suggest', {
      provider: {
        suggest: (function(request, options) {

          return ymaps.suggest(city + ", " + request)
          })
        }}
      )
    }
```

Comment: Работает как часы!